# Remove splash screen in xcode 4.6.3 using iPad simulator 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, splash-screen

How do you remove the Splash screen in xcode, I have tried deleting all of the pictures, project -> clean etc.

I am using xcode 4.6.3
iPad simulator 6.1

I have tried many other answers on the web.. the main trend seems to be delete the app from the simulator then rebuild it, but I cant find the directory of the simulator to delete the app.

Any help would be great,

Thanks.

Comment: Having no launch image visually appears the same as having a black launch image.

Comment: If you are planning to post your app to itunes then you NEED to have splash pics, let it even be blank. Your binary validation will fail as it won't have Default@2x, Default, Default-568h@2x pics

Comment: Done, sorry thought I previously accepted it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about resetting the simulator?

> iOS Simulator -> Reset contents and settings

Comment: Once the simulator is opened, go to the top bar and click on iOS Simulator -> Reset contents and settings.

Comment: Have you also removed the picture from the Project - Summary screen?

Comment: got it all working now, thanks! I feel like such a n00b haha.

Answer (score 0):

first way this is delete splash screen in Project -> Target -> Summary -> Launch images -> right click -> delete

second way this is remove all 'Default*.png' images like Default@2x, Default, Default-568h@2x,etc

[image: something like this]